# Generic list by using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-list

I have a scenario on which i got `Class name as a string` I just want to create a  generic `List` of that class. I tried the following

```
            Type _type = Type.GetType(className);

            List<_type> list = new List<_type>();
```

But iam geting `error`. I can't gave that _type as list argument. If anybody knows please help me

Comment: Why would you do that? I bet you 1000$, that what you are trying to do is something stupid and will result in bad design.

Comment: This seems like a potentially bad pattern. Can you provide some more detail about what this is intended to solve? Why is your class name coming through in a string? Is this part of some kind of custom serializer?

Comment: But i just want to generalize the scenario... Actually my need is return generic list from DataAccess itself. also want to generalize the methode..

Comment: Then you don't need generics, but you can use non-generic List.

Comment: @Euphoric If you dnt mind can you please explain?

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx instead. Generics are for compile-time type safety. Using reflection like Markus says will take that away. So end result when using this class same. Except runtime type-checking, but you should do that beforehand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closest you can get:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(_type);
IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Comment: Is it possible if the _type class is in another class library?

Comment: As long as `_type` is referencing it.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection takes place during runtime, as the type of an object could be changed to anything by a running program.

Type parameters (generics), on the other hand, are only used by the compiler, to check type safety.

So it's not possible to use reflection specify a type parameter, because the compiler will not know anything about the result of reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4, then using `dynamic` may help.  In this case you will be able to use methods on the instance that are not accessible through non-generic interfaces (such as `IList`).

For example, using `dynamic` allows you to invoke the `AddRanges` method of the list, which you couldn't do through a cast to `IList`:

```
Type _type = typeof(int);
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(_type); 
dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType); 

list.Add(1);   
list.AddRange(new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3});
```

However, this method is not as nearly as type-safe as casting to a non-generic interface, because it cannot catch errors at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible as generics need to be known at compile time. You are trying to redefine this by making them known at runtime. The reason they need to be known at compile time is so the compiler can verify that all variables passed to it are valid. AFAIK, doing what you want to go would require a complete rewrite of generics.

The main reason behind compile time checking is that `_type` can change at runtime and then there would be overhead in adding to the `List<T>` as the JIT compiler would need to do type checking.

What @MarkusJarderot said is the closest you can get as interfaces are used instead of generics.