# Refer to Self's Type inside a class

Tags: c#, types, self

in my C# class, I want to refer to type of the class itself, is it possible?

my sample code:

in the line of

```
private static List<CRcpParmPropEle<CParam1, string>> ParmPropList;
```

I don't want to use "CParam1", I wish to use some general way (like "this") to refer to itself. because I have many classes like CParam1, everyone would need to refer to itself this way.

```
class CParam1
{

    private double m_Prop1;

    private static List<CRcpParmPropEle<CParam1, string>> ParmPropList;

    public CParam1()
    {

    }

    ////-> I wish to replace Cparam1 to something like this
    public static List<CRcpParmPropEle<CParam1, string>> getParmPropList()
    {
        if (ParmPropList == null)
        {                
            ParmPropList.Add(new CRcpParmPropEle<CParam1, string>("Prop1", "BA", 0, false));
            //-> I wish to replace Cparam1 to something like this
        }
        return ParmPropList;
    }

    public string Prop1
    {
        get
        {
                return m_Prop1.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            m_Prop1 = -1;
            double dW1;
            if (double.TryParse(value, out dW1))
            {
                    m_Prop1 = dW1;
            }
        }
    }

public class CRcpParmPropEle<T,TProp>
{
    public Func<T, TProp> getter;
    public Action<T, TProp> setter;

    public string PropName { get; set; }
    public string ColPos { get; set; }
    public int ColNum { get; set; }
    public int RowNum { get; set; }

    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

    public CRcpParmPropEle(string strPropName, string strColPos, int nRowNum, bool bReadOnly)
    {
        PropName = strPropName;
        ColPos = strColPos;
        RowNum = nRowNum;

        ReadOnly = bReadOnly;

        var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(PropName);    //typeof(rcpObj).GetProperty(propName);
        getter = (Func<T,TProp>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T,TProp>), prop.GetGetMethod());
        setter = (Action<T,TProp>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<T,TProp>), prop.GetSetMethod());            
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `this.GetType()`?

Comment: Is it an option to have your CParam1 type class derive from a common base class or implement a common interface? This would allow you have the list type refer to the common base or interface rather than the class itself. Also, given that this list is already static, what about having it live elsewhere?

Comment: @slugster, the type name is in the declaration of the type of a static property of the class.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @DWright Yeah, good point, but often methods/field are static because tools like Resharper suggest it rather than because they need to be. IOW does the method/field need to be static, in which case you can refer to `this`?

Comment: for the common base class, I am not sure if it works when I retrieve the property methods of the inheriting classes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. There is no way to do this. Since in the contexts where this would typically be used, one is writing code specific to the type anyway, and since we are used to having to specify the type name for static members anyway, this doesn't seem like much of a hardship.

But, there are a couple of alternatives that could work in your scenario, both involving generics.

The first is to delegate the construction of the new object to a generic helper method:

```
public static List<CRcpParmPropEle<CParam1, string>> getParmPropList()
{
    if (ParmPropList == null)
    {
        AddToList(ParmPropList, "Prop1", "BA", 0, false);
    }
    return ParmPropList;
}

private static void AddToList<T>(List<CRcpParmPropEle<T, string>> list, string s1, string s2, int i, bool f)
{
    list.Add(new CRcpParmPropEle<T, string>(s1, s2, i, f));
}
```

In this way, the actual type is inferred from the type of the `List<T>` object being passed in, and so doesn't need to be restated. Of course, you don't get out of specifying the type *somewhere*. It just doesn't wind up at this particular call site.

Another option is to use a static helper class to implement the static functionality of your `CParam1` class:

```
static class ParmPropClass<T>
{
    private static List<CRcpParmPropEle<T, string>> ParmPropList;

    public static List<CRcpParmPropEle<T, string>> getParmPropList()
    {
        if (ParmPropList == null)
        {
            ParmPropList.Add(new CRcpParmPropEle<T, string>("Prop1", "BA", 0, false));
        }
        return ParmPropList;
    }
}
```

Then when you use the static members, you have to specify the type name as `ParmPropClass<CParam1>` (or whatever, depending on what you wind up naming the helper class). Again, you don't get out of specifying the type name somewhere, but the call site doesn't need to.

In fact, if you are doing this kind of pattern *exactly* in a number of locations, the generic helper type might be a better way to go, since then you don't have to copy/paste code all the time (a recipe for failing to fix some bug in all the places it was copied to).

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward or easy to implement answer here. I'll give you three options but I don't think any of these would be easier than just changing all of the classes. If I had to do this right I would use a dependency injector. in the long run you will be better off and you'll be able to handle this stuff easier next time around. If I had to do it fast and desperate I would use reflection.

**Option 1 - Reflection**

You could assemble the List at runtime using reflection. 
Look at this post for an example of creating a list at runtime with reflection.
[Generic list by using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509695/generic-list-by-using-reflection)

*This will make your code really nasty to maintain and you will have to use reflection throughout to manage the list. You would probably add more headaches in runtime errors and difficulty debugging than just changing it everywhere*

**Option 2 - Common Base Class**

If you can make all the CPARAM1 type objects implement from a common base class CPARAMBASE you could define the list using the common base class.

```
private static List<CRcpParmPropEle<CParamBase, string>> ParmPropList;
```

**Option 3 - Dependency Injection**

This isn't something you can just cover in a SO answer but look at dependency injection.

You create an interface between all of the CPARAM type classes and then you inject a concrete type for based on what type it is being injected into.

```
   [Inject]
   private static List<CRcpParmPropEle<ICParam, string>> ParmPropList;
```

In your dependency Injection you could define that ICParam instance would be.

```
this.Bind<List<CRcpParmPropEle<ICParam, string>>>()
    .To<List<CRcpParmPropEle<CParam1, string>>>()
    .WhenInjectedInto(typeof(CParam1));
```

Look up Ninject and then Contextual Binding and http://www.ninject.org/wiki.html