# How to determine type between angle brackets in List<> at run time?

Tags: c#

[image]

Hi everybody
My code snippet is attached, according to that, when i determine type between the angle bracket there is no problem, but i want to determine type at run time, how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't attach a picture of the code, include the code

Comment: Did you even read the error? You're *assigning* the type to `t`. `t` is now a variable *holding* a type. `List<a.GetType()>` would be closer.

Comment: Yes, i read the error. my question is:
Is there any way to determine type between the angle brackets at run time?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve besides the error?

Comment: It's likely you want to rethink the design that lead you to thinking you need to do this ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) or you'll need to use reflection.  Also it's not clear if you have a list and you want to know it's generic type or you have a type and want to dynamically create a list for it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve besides the error?

Comment: Use generic methods. but you have to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you can determine type only at run time, you need to use reflection. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14888221/3872935

Comment: What do you have the list in at runtime, an object? A strongly typed value and you are working inside a generic method? Or do you mean you know the type at runtime and want to create the list? (Which is what you seem to be trying to do in that picture).

Comment: `but i want to determine type at run time` you *have* to use reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic list by using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509695/generic-list-by-using-reflection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to initialize a generic list in run-time, you have to use reflection.

```
Type t = a.GetType();
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
IList list = (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

Comment: Thanks bro. it is exactly what i want.